# Web agent and web service time out can stop http hang in domino?

Tags: xpages

If any web agent at any chance falls in to infinite loop can "Web agent time out parameter"(say 5 sec) in server document prevent http hang? If the agent is called from Xpage postSaveDocument will also apply the same?

Comment: What is your experience when you try it on a development server?

Comment: We have not done yet on dev and not faced infinite loop issue; but some days ago http hung in one production server all of sudden and not able to identify the respective URL yet so asking if possible to kindly explain this and with background reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have installed domino server in my system and tried; this agent is not stopped with this server parameter, but restart task http can stop it so it is not like xpage infinite loop which never stops unless sever is forcefully killed. Thanks a lot for your input.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is exactly what that parameter does - and it's been in the Domino server at least since version 5.0. [See this response on the old forum](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/nd6forum.nsf/869c7412fe5d56b7852569fa007826e3/725d6b29fbf6d9f685256d9700822711?OpenDocument).

So basically, you need to edit the server document, go to "Internet Protocols", "Domino Web Engine". Near the bottom you can set the timeout in seconds for "Web agents and Web Services Timeout".

I can't see there should be any difference in ***how*** the web agent is called :-)

/John